# How can i set pixels of whole screen with x86 assembly without any BIOS interrupts?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
 .MODEL SMALL
 .CODE
start:
 mov ax,012h ;VGA mode
 int 10h ;640 x 480 16 colors.
 mov ax,0A000h
 mov es,ax ;ES points to the video memory.
 mov dx,03C4h ;dx = indexregister
 mov ax,0F02h ;INDEX = MASK MAP, 
 out dx,ax ;write all the bitplanes.
 mov di,0 ;DI pointer in the video memory.
 mov cx,38400 ;(640 * 480)/8 = 38400
 mov ax,0FFh ;write to every pixel.
 rep stosb ;fill the screen
 mov ah,4ch ;go back 
 int 21h ; to DOS.
 END start
```

The code above only set pixels of Dos screen, I want to change every pixel on my monitor, is it possible with x86 assembly in user mode?

Comment: It is only possible if DOS is your actual operating system. If you're running it under Windows, then Windows manages the screen buffer and won't let you touch it directly.

Answer (score 0):

What does "Dos screen" mean?

If you are using a DOS emulation under Windows or Linux, then this emulation emulates a computer and the "Dos screen" is what the "whole screen" of a real machine running DOS would display.

Of course it is not possible to set any pixels "outside" the screen so you cannot set any pixels outside the "Dos screen".

You may run the DOS emulator in full-screen mode...

Comment: "you cannot set any pixels outside the "Dos screen"" so how can windows programs write pixel to the screen? What should they do to do so?

Comment: @bluejayke We have one constraint in the original question: The user wants to write an MS-DOS program running inside an MS-DOS emulation (such as DOSEMU or QEMU). Windows programs do not run in such an emulation. Of course: Theoretically, it would be possible to connect a second tool (e.g. an X11 server) using the network system of the DOS emulator...

Comment: oh interesting, but is it possible to write, in windows, pixels to the screen without going through the windows API?

Comment: @bluejayke No. No modern OS running on a computer with an MMU allows direct access to the hardware. You must use the OS' API to access the screen. When using the MS-DOS emulator, the emulator itself uses the Windows API to copy the data from the emulated display RAM to the real screen.

Answer (score 0):

In text mode, set ES to 0b800h. Set di to (number of current row*numbers of colums+current column)*2. Set ah to (8*bgcolor(0-7)+foregroundcolor)+(+128, if text should blink). If the current screenpage isn't 0 you should add the number of the screenpage multiplied with (the offset of the last char on screen+2). Set the ASCII code in al (e.g. 65 for A) and write ax  with stosw. Example:

```
mov ax, 0b800h
mov es, ax   ;set es register to video memory
mov di, (2*(5*80+0))  ;(nullbased) row:6, col: 1 
mov ah, (5*16+2)  ; bgcolor:5 foreground: 2
mov al, 65   ;ASCII of A
stosw
```

In 320x200 graphics mode with 256 colors, set ES to 0a000h. There the program has to set pixels instead of letters.
If you  want to use the graphics mode, set ax to 19 and call int 10h, before writign on the screen, because changing ES won't change the video mode.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning i have also used 16 color graphic modes. But with 16 colors graphic modes we need to have at minimum one port access for to set one pixel to the screen. And this port access is very slow. All other regular graphic modes with 8,15,16,24,32 bit colors are much easier to use (like van Uitkon said in the comment).

Here is one of my first little programs with using 16 colors. In the pixel set routine below i show how to set a singel pixel to the screen with using a 16 color graphic mode.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.386
.CODE
 ORG 0100h

       MOV     AX, @DATA
       MOV     DS, AX
       MOV     ES, AX
       MOV     AX, 0A000h
       MOV     FS, AX

       MOV     AX, 12h       ; Mode 640 x 480 x 4 bit color
       INT   10h

P10B:  MOV     AX, 140h      ; X Position
       MOV     BX, 0F0h      ; Y Position
P111:  MOV     CX, 1         ; Radius
       MOV     [XPOS], AX    ; Edit: need right square bracket, was "}" before
       MOV     [YPOS], BX    ; Edit: need right square bracket, was "}" before
       MOV     [RADI], CX
       MOV     [R0E], AX
       ADD     AX, CX

P200:  MOV     GS, AX
       MOV     AX, [R0E]
       SUB     AX, [XPOS]
       ADD     AX, [YPOS]
       MOV     [R10], AX
       SUB     AX, [YPOS]
       MOV     [R14], AX
       MOV     AX, [R0E]
       SUB     AX, [XPOS]
       XOR     SI, SI
       MOV     DI, 2
       CALL P600
       MOV     AX, [R14]
       MOV     SI, 2
       XOR     DI, DI
       CALL P600
       MOV     AX, GS
       INC    WORD PTR [R0E]
       CMP     [R0E], AX
       JNZ P200

       INC    BYTE PTR CS:[P111+1]       ; increase Radius
       CMP    BYTE PTR CS:[P111+1], 0E0h
       JNZ P10B
       MOV    BYTE PTR CS:[P111+1], 1

TASTE: MOV     AX, 1
       INT   16h
       CMP     AL, 20h                   ; space key
       JNZ TASTE
       MOV     AX, 3                     ; Text-Mode
       INT   10h
       MOV     AX, 4C00h
       INT   21h

;--------------------- S u b - Routinen ------------------------------

P600:  MUL     AX
       MOV     [SI+R18], AX
       MOV     AX, [RADI]
       MUL     AX
       MOV     [R16], AX
       SUB     AX, [SI+R18]
       MOV     CX, AX

       MOV     DX, 1
       MOV     BX, 1
P406:  STC
       SBB     CX, DX
       JB  P411
       INC     BX
       ADD     DX, 2
       JMP  P406

P411:  ADD     BX, [DI+XPOS]
       MOV     [DI+R06], BX
       SUB     BX, [DI+XPOS]
       MOV     AX, [DI+XPOS]
       SUB     AX, BX
       MOV     [DI+R0A], AX
       MOV     AX, [SI+R0E]
       MOV     [SI+R06], AX
       SUB     AX, [SI+XPOS]
       MOV     BX, [SI+XPOS]
       SUB     BX, AX
       MOV     [SI+R0A], BX

       MOV     BP, [R06]
       MOV     BX, [R08]
       CALL PIXEL
       MOV     BP, [R06]   ; Edit: undifined symbol R069
       MOV     BX, [R0C]
       CALL PIXEL
       MOV     BP, [R0A]
       MOV     BX, [R08]
       CALL PIXEL
       MOV     BP, [R0A]
       MOV     BX, [R0C]

PIXEL: MOV     CX, BP        ; BP = X  /  BX = Y
       SHR     CX, 3
       MOV     AX, 50h       ; Lenght of scanline
       MUL     BX
       ADD     AX, CX
       MOV     SI, AX
       INC     CX
       MOV     AX, CX
       SHL     AX, 3
       SUB     AX, BP
       DEC     AX
       MOV     CL, AL
       MOV     AH, 1         ; 2 ^ (((X/8) + 1) * 8 - X) - 1
       SHL     AH, CL        ;  = Pixel pos.
       MOV     DX, 3CEh
       MOV     AL, 8         ; Pixel-Mask
       OUT     DX, AX
       MOV     AX, 205h      ; Write Mode 2
       OUT     DX, AX
       MOV     AH, 5         ; color
       MOV     AL, FS:[SI]   ; dummy read for to adjust the address
       MOV    FS:[SI], AH
       RET

.DATA

XPOS   DW ?
YPOS   DW ?
RADI   DW ?
R06    DW ?
R08    DW ?
R0A    DW ?
R0C    DW ?
R0E    DW ?
R10    DW ?
R14    DW ?
R16    DW ?
R18    DW ?

.STACK 20h
 END
```

Sorry for the error i edit the error lines now.